# have columns of different size of Dataframe with multiIndex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to have a Dataframe like this:

```
              a   b   c  
 ----- ----- --- --- --- 
  foo   one   1   2   0  
        two   2   2      
  bar   one   3   1   1  
        two   4   1
```

that ['foo','bar'] and ['one','two'] are indices.
the column c has the size same as index ['foo','bar']

or its only possible to have the Dataframe like this

```
              a   b   c  
 ----- ----- --- --- --- 
  foo   one   1   2   0  
        two   2   2   0  
  bar   one   3   1   1  
        two   4   1   1
```

Comment: For column c, are you okay with the empty cells being NaN type or do you want them to hold a blank string?

Answer (score 0):

for column c, if you are okay with NaN type this should work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_data = {'lvl0':['foo','foo','bar','bar'],
           'lvl1':['one','two','one','two'],
           'a':[1,2,3,4],
           'b':[2,2,1,1],
           'c':[0,np.nan,1,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
df.set_index(['lvl0','lvl1'])
```

Comment: then the element of [('foo','two'), 'c'] will be nan, thank u but that not what I need.

Comment: I see. Do you want c to be in the index?

Comment: yea, I have thought about it. but what if c is a sparse column with numbers of nan, and what if c is a column of objects. I don't know whether it still works or whether it is suitable to make c as index